# pymedia.audio.sound - How do I get up and running with this module?

Tags: python

Im trying to get my hands on this pymedia.audio.sound module and have attempted to get it several times from python.org, but I think I am doing something wrong like.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Im running Windows XP, Python 2.5 and its running fine, but how do I download and where do I extract the new module to be able to use it?

Apologies for my apparent lack of intelligence.

Cheers

---

When I execute the file "setup.py" I get the following output:

Using WINDOWS configuration...

Path for  OGG not found.

Path for  VORBIS not found.

Path for  FAAD not found.

Path for  MP3LAME not found.

Path for  VORBISENC not found.

Path for  ALSA not found.

Continue building pymedia ? [Y,n]:

Answer (score 0):

The homepage for [pymedia](http://pymedia.org/).
Download from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pymedia/files/pymedia/).

Extract the compressed tar file. Then run `python setup.py install` from the extracted directory.